# "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Cannot parse null string" dont know why this isnt working , any advice?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
package cs3220.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import cs3220.model.Games;

@WebServlet("/DisplayGame")
public class DisplayGame extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DisplayGame() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Games getEntry(int id) {
        Games entry = new Games();
        Connection c = null;

        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://cs3.calstatela.edu/cs3220stu16";
            String username = "foo";
            String password = "bar";

            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            String sql = "select * from games_list where id = ?";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstmt.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {

                entry.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                entry.setRating(rs.getInt("rating"));

                entry.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                entry.setComment(rs.getString("comment"));

            }
            pstmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return entry;
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        DisplayGame ds = new DisplayGame();

        request.setAttribute("entry", ds.getEntry(id));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/DisplayGame.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

I usually do a seperate class for all the sql methods and just call it in the servlet but I wanted to figure out how to do it a different way. What i am doing is using a seperate method for the entry data from database, I want to display a certian data using id so it doesn't loop all of the data when i want to display a "game".

Comment: *DisplayGame ds = new DisplayGame();* You don't want that. You already have an instance, so you can just call `request.setAttribute("entry", getEntry(id));`

Comment: Thank you for including sample code. In general, in questions like this, it is helpful to highlight the line in the code that triggered the error. Here is an example, albeit one that does not represent this issue:  `foo = bar [x]; // ArrayOutOfBoundsException on this line`

Comment: Something like this will help debug your code: `String idStr = request.getParameter ("id"); System.out.println (idStr); int  id = Integer.parseInt (idStr);`